# create dynamic node with jstree methode

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have been struggling with problem this for hours
I have successfully created a folder tree with [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/). But I couldn't append new folders dynamically to it,
here is the link to the create_node method

```
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=(&f=create_node([obj, node, pos, callback, is_loaded])
```

My Implementation :

```
var parentid = 6 // just an example
$('#folderTree').jstree().create_node(parentid , 'new node' );
```

please help

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the solution

I must set 'check_callback' : true, otherwise all operations like create, rename... are prevented.